# Decrypting PHP MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 in Ruby

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, mcrypt

I have a database filled with encrypted passwords that I need to decrypt in Ruby for a platform change. How can I port this PHP code to Ruby? Have tried to use OpenSSL in Ruby with AES_256 but getting 'Bad Decrypt' errors and also errors that my key ($salt) isn't long enough.

In the example below, $salt is a 25 character string.

This is the PHP decryption function:

```
function decrypt_password($text, $salt)
{
    return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
        $salt, base64_decode($text), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, 
        mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB),
        MCRYPT_RAND)));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` algorithm does *not* implement AES, it implements Rijndael using a 256 bit block size. This is not a default mode, you can find an implementation for Ruby [here](https://github.com/singlebrook/crypt/blob/master/crypt/rijndael.rb).

Furthermore, you seem to be using the `$salt` variable as a key. Keys are automatically extended to the next available key size. For 25 *byte* keys I presume a 256 bit (32 byte) key will be used. This is the `$salt` value, extended with bytes valued `00`. Note that I'm *presuming* that each character is encoded as a single byte on your system.

As a final surprise, you may safely disregard the `mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND)` part of the code, as ECB mode does not use an IV, so the value it returns is fully ignored. Note that using ECB mode for strings - and therefore also passwords of course - is not secure.

You should, at the very minimum use AES CBC with a random IV. And you should consider using [bcrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php) instead of encryption if you don't need the value of the passwords itself.

Comment: Note that I found the Ruby code using an internet search, no guarantees from my part that it even works.

Comment: Aware of the ECB issue... this is not my code but someone else's, hence the transition! :) Thanks, taking a look!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to kick the colleague when you meet :P

Comment: I'm going to use a bit of a different solution (essentially call back to the PHP code) as it's going to result in doing this a bit more easily so I'm accepting your answer

Comment: Broken link for `crypt` gem and I wasn't able to find documentation on rubygems. Petr's answer worked for me though.

Comment: @TheLonelyGhost A quick search showed that it probably moved to [github here](https://github.com/singlebrook/crypt/blob/master/crypt/rijndael.rb)

Comment: @owlstead I found the [rubygems](https://rubygems.org/gems/crypt) entry, but the docs are non-existent. Thanks for the github link though.

Comment: @TheLonelyGhost Welcome to the wonderful world of crypto, where whole empires are build on one person crypto libraries :P

Answer (score 5):

There is a ruby library for mcrypt as well. See below for a sample implementation:

```
require 'mcrypt'
require 'base64'

# base64_decode() equivalent
encrypted = Base64.decode64(text)

# preparing Mcrypt library for Rijndael cipher, 256 bits, ECB mode
cipher = Mcrypt.new(:rijndael_256, :ecb, salt, nil, :zeros)

# padding required
encrypted = encrypted.ljust((encrypted.size / 32.0).ceil * 32, "\0") 

# decrypt using Rijndael
decrypted = cipher.decrypt(encrypted).strip
```

Dependencies: `libmcrypt`

- `sudo apt-get install libmcrypt-dev` (Ubuntu/Debian)
- `sudo yum install libmcrypt-devel` (RHEL/CentOS/Fedora)

Gems: `mcrypt`

- `gem install ruby-mcrypt`

Comment: Other answer was informative, but this was the one that actually answered the *exact same question* I had. Just confirmed after using ruby to ETL 300,000+ records that needed to be decrypted. Thanks!

Comment: @TheLonelyGhost That's a very large edit, can you explain what you did in there? And why the code had to be altered to such a large degree?

Comment: @owlstead I added comments explaining each line, refactored the code to exactly fit variable names given in the question for added clarity, and noted dependencies and how to install them on a few platforms. This hopefully clarified the original poster's intent.

Comment: OK, approved it. Thanks for the edit. Petr, this is an extensive edit, please roll back if you don't agree - it seems good to me.

Comment: Seems good to me. Thanks @TheLonelyGhost for changing my raw code snippet to real answer.